# How to determine position of specific character/string in SQLite string column value?

Tags: sqlite

I have values in a SQLite table`*` that contain a number of strings, of different lengths, joined by periods, something like this:

```
SomeApp.SomeNameSpace.InterestingString.NotInteresting
SomeApp.OtherNameSpace.WantThisOne.ReallyQuiteDull
SomeApp.OtherNameSpace.WantThisOne.AlsoDull
SomeApp.DifferentNameSpace.AlwaysWorthALook.LittleValue
```

I'd like to extract (in this case) the third period-delimited substring so I could write something like

```
SELECT interesting_string, COUNT(*)
FROM ( SELECT third_part_of_period_delimited_string(name) interesting_string )
GROUP BY interesting_string;
```

Obviously I can do this any number of ways programmatically; I'm wondering if there's any way to achieve this in a SQLite SELECT query?

`*` It's a SharpDevelop Profiler database, if anyone's curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can, as you mention, work with the strings after you have selected them from the database.  Or you can split them up into separate columns when they are stored.

If you do not have access to the code that is storing the data, you might want to consider reading the data in its entirety, splitting the strings and storing the split out tokens in separate columns in a new table.  If the data is not too large, you might look at storing this table in a new memory database to give excellent performance.

Whether this is worthwhile depends on whether one pass to split the data strings can be made use of many times.  If the data is constantly changing, then this scheme would probably not work well.

Comment: I don't create the data, unfortunately, just consume it. For known substrings I can use an ugly constructL `CASE WHEN LIKE() THEN ""` ... but I was hoping I'd missed something. Ho hum.